# Logging in through Facebook, if not registered, should redirect to registration page

Tags: facebook

My site has the option of registering with and without facebook. When you register with facebook though, extra information is needed. This is fine, as I use fb:registration and specify extra fields.

However, the problem is, when a user comes to the site and hasn't registered, sees the facebook login button and clicks it, the link brings them to facebook to login and the app is registered and bypasses the registration form I have.

I there a way to redirect a non-registered user that is not logged in with facebook to a registration page instead of adding the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `registration-url` parameter to the login button as [documented](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/) in the Login + Registration Flows section.

`<fb:login-button 
registration-url="yoururl" />`

This isn't documented so I don't know if it will continue to work but if your using the HTML5 version of the login button then you can use:

`<div class="fb-login-button" data-registration-url="yoururl">Login with Facebook</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure i understood you but..

Going on the assumption that you only want users who have an active FB browser session and have authorized the use of your application with their account to see your login button/a particular page you could try this right after your `FB.init`:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) { 
    if(notLoggedIntoYourSite && response.status != 'connected') {
        // Redirect user or hide login button
    }
})
```

Ref: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/